# New to C++ can't figure out where I am going wrong. Expected unqualified-id:23

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and Ive looked at similar problems cant figure out where mine goes wrong. I know its something simple but im just doing random things and hoping it will run. There error is with the semi colon on line 23. Expected unqualified-id:23. I think it has something to do with the semi colon but i cant figure out what is wrong with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const double income_limit_mo = 37750; // max income for missouri
    const double income_limit_ks = 34500; // max income for kansas
    const double credit_rate = 0.0975; // tax credit of 9.75%
    char homeowner_status;
    string state;
    double income;
    double credit_amount;

    cout << "Are you a homeowner [Y/N]? ";
    cin >> homeowner_status;
    cout << endl;

    if (homeowner_status == 'Y' || homeowner_status == 'y')
        cout << "Resident State [MO or KS]:  ";
        cin >> state;}
{
        if (state == "MO" || state == "Mo" || state == "mo")
            {cout << "  Amount of annual income: ";
            cin >> income;

             if (income <= income_limit_mo)
                { credit_amount = (income * credit_rate);
                cout << "Allowed amount of credit: $ ";
                cout << credit_amount;}
            else
                cout << "Applicant ineligible. Income too high";}

        else if (state == "KS" || state == "Ks" || state == "ks")
            {cout << "Amount of annual income: ";

             if (income <= income_limit_ks)
                {credit_amount = (income * credit_rate);
                cout << "Allowed amount of credit: $ ";
                cout << credit_amount;}
             else
                cout << "Applicant ineligible. Income too high";}

        else
            cout << "Applicant ineligible. Not Missouri or Kansas resident.";
    else
        cout << "Applicant ineligible. Not a homeowner."









    




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> state;}` this ends your `main()` function. Write more readable code, then these errors are easier to spot. Run your code through clang-format for example. There's also an online page where you can fix code formatting with clang-format if you for some reason can't install clang-format on your system: http://format.krzaq.cc/

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing semicolon at the end of the line 48, but you also have an issue of curly brackets. Here's what I got after corrections, but pay attention to your if/else logic. I recommend to use always { and } curly brackets even for 1-line if/else statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    const double income_limit_mo = 37750;  // max income for missouri
    const double income_limit_ks = 34500;  // max income for kansas
    const double credit_rate = 0.0975;  // tax credit of 9.75%
    char homeowner_status;
    string state;
    double income;
    double credit_amount;

    cout << "Are you a homeowner [Y/N]? ";
    cin >> homeowner_status;
    cout << endl;

    if (homeowner_status == 'Y' || homeowner_status == 'y') {
        cout << "Resident State [MO or KS]:  ";
        cin >> state;

        if (state == "MO" || state == "Mo" || state == "mo") {
            cout << "  Amount of annual income: ";
            cin >> income;

            if (income <= income_limit_mo) {
                credit_amount = (income * credit_rate);
                cout << "Allowed amount of credit: $ ";
                cout << credit_amount;
            }
            else
                cout << "Applicant ineligible. Income too high";
        }

        else
            if (state == "KS" || state == "Ks" || state == "ks") {
                cout << "Amount of annual income: ";

                if (income <= income_limit_ks) {
                    credit_amount = (income * credit_rate);
                    cout << "Allowed amount of credit: $ ";
                    cout << credit_amount;
                }
                else
                    cout << "Applicant ineligible. Income too high";
            }
            else
                cout << "Applicant ineligible. Not Missouri or Kansas resident.";
    }
    else
        cout << "Applicant ineligible. Not a homeowner.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One-liners are less problem here. Not aligning closing braces with its logical indentation is more confusing. Your style with opening braces after a space also doesn't belong to most fortunate ones. Especially for new learners most "visible" one is typical K&R vertically aligned style.

Comment: @bloody, thanks for the comment, this is not my favorite style of if/else, but I was trying to make it more explicit with minimal changes of the original code.